# Multiple input (result name) in Struts2

Tags: validation, struts2

I am working on an application that is using `Struts2` framework. In action class I got two `validate`methods, one for each action. In `struts.xml` I have `input` to validate a method and returns a corresponding a view but for the other action that needs validation too, how this approach would work? The only thing I need to know is whether I can change the default `input` to something else so that method2 gets validated if not then how can I go to different view after actions are validated.

Action Class:

```java
public void validateSearch() {
    // validation
}

public void validateSubmit() {
    // validation
}

// Action Methods

public String search() {
    // business logic
}

public String submit() {
    // business logic
}
```

struts.xml

```xml
<result name="input">search.jsp</result>
<result name="????">submit.jsp</result>
```

In case of two `input` I don't get my views the way I want them. For submit I get a view of search. is there any way to configure this.

Comment: what do you mean by 2 actions?

Comment: Two actions methods, one for search()[] and one for submit()[]

Comment: The input result is configurable.

Comment: @Roman. This is what I want to know. How to configure the result input because by default validate looks for input correct. Just for testing I changed the input to some other text and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using DMI (which is deprecated and highly discouraged), and have something like this:

```xml
<action name="foo" class="foo.bar.fooAction">
    <result name="success">foo.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">search.jsp</result>
</action>
```

You simply need to turn your two action methods into two real actions, like follows:

```xml
<action name="fooSearch" class="foo.bar.fooAction" method="search">
    <result name="success">foo.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">search.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="fooSubmit" class="foo.bar.fooAction" method="submit">
    <result name="success">foo.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">submit.jsp</result>
</action>
```

then instead of:

```xml
<s:submit action="foo" method="search" />
<s:submit action="foo" method="submit" />
```

something like:

```xml
<s:submit action="fooSearch" />
<s:submit action="fooSubmit" />
```

Comment: I am using DMI and I am configuring my actions the way you did it but the problem is how to validate them, since both action methods and validate methods for both actions methods are in the same Class.

Comment: **Exactly** like you're doing. If you use `validate()`, it will apply to *every* action method (or action, as in this answer) of the Java class. If you want a validation to apply for a single method only, you can use `validateNAME_OF_THE_METHOD()` and it will run only for that method. So `validateSearch()` will only run for `search()`, and so on. P.S: please consider upvoting the answer if you like it, thank you :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Not *exactly*. OP is using DMI

Comment: OP *was* using DMI; he's not using it anymore if he dropped method="" for action="" (although that's a *kind* of DMI itself, it's not DMI). Also OP has already accepted the answer so this seems futile

Answer (score 0):

ok, since you are still looking fro answers I will tell you that `input` name for result is conventional. You can change it any time if your action class implements [`ValidationWorkflowAware`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ValidationWorkflowAware.html).

> `ValidationWorkflowAware` classes can programmatically change result name when errors occurred This interface can be only applied to action which already implements `ValidationAware` interface!

```java
public void validateSubmit() {
    // validation
    if (hasErrors())
        setInputResultName("inputSubmit");
}
```

The result config

```xml
<result name="inputSubmit">submit.jsp</result>
```